# Equivalent pandas function to this R aggregation

Tags: r, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`, with `lon`, `lat` and `label` columns

I want to perform the equivalent of this R aggregation:

```
mean_labels <- aggregate(cbind(lon, lat) ~ label, data=df, FUN=mean)
```

But it's significantly too magical for me. As far as I can tell, it's computing the mean of the `lat`, `lon` values for each group of `label` values in df

However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this using a pandas dataframe. I can easily group by `label`, but I don't know how I then compute the mean `lon` and `lat`values within each group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* this is the same as doing a groupby label then aggregating by mean:

```
g = df.groupby('label')

mean_labels  = g[['lon', 'lat']].mean()
```

That is, for each label you take the average values of lon and lat.
(...this seems like a reasonable thing to do.)

Comment: I think you can directly call `mean` on `GroupBy` objects, and it will be faster than passing `np.mean` into `agg` and will handle `NaN` values, unless the name of the function maps to one bottleneck or numpy nan* functions

Comment: @cpcloud Good point! I think everyone would agree the pandas syntax is better... :)